# HTML Entity problems using Nokogiri::XML.fragment

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, libxml2

it seems that all entities are killed using

```
tags = "<p>test umlauts &ouml;</p>"
Nokogiri::XML.fragment(tags)
```

Result:

```
<p>test umlauts </p>
```

The above method calls `Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(tags)` and that methods calls
`Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.new(XML::Document.new, tags)`.

In relation to the nokogiri documentation this code will be executed:

```
def initialize document, tags=nil
    if tags
      parser = if self.kind_of?(Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment)
                 HTML::SAX::Parser.new(FragmentHandler.new(self, tags))
               else
                 XML::SAX::Parser.new(FragmentHandler.new(self, tags))
               end
      parser.parse(tags)
    end
end
```

I think we are dealing with the XML::SAX::Parser and the corresponding FragmentHandler. Digging around the code gives no hint; which parameters do I have to set to get the correct result?

Answer (score 3):

oouml is not a predefined entity in XML. If you want to allow the HTML entity references in XHTML you'd need to use a parser that read the external DTD in the doctype. This is a lot of effort; you may prefer to just use the HTML parser if you have HTML-compatible XHTML with entity references.

Comment: Nokogiri::HTML.fragment("<p>test umlauts &oouml;</p>") =>  <p>test umlauts &amp;oouml;</p>. This is not, what I want. You are right - to read the external DTD is a lot effort....

Comment: hang on... ‘oouml’?? That's not a defined entity even in HTML! Shouldn't that be ‘ouml’?

Comment: Nokogiri::HTML.fragment("<p>test umlauts &ouml;</p>") works! Thank you!